# Clean up the data, wrap numbers in <dd> & wrap text in <dt> with jQuery

Tags: jquery, match

I was able to turn a long string into a dl list as shown below:

```
 <div class="classA">
   <dl id="idA"> Display # 252215425:  </dl>
   <dl id="idB">3 Apples   </dl>
   <dl id="idC">3 Peaches   </dl>
   <dl id="idD">10 Seadless Watermelons   </dl>
   <dl id="idE">23 Bananas </dl>
 </div>
```

The result I want is:

```
 <div class="classA">
   <dl id="idA"> 
       <dd>252215425</dd>
       <dt>Display #</dt>
   </dl>

   <dl id="idB"> 
       <dd>3</dd>
       <dt>Apples</dt>
   </dl>

   <dl id="idC"> 
       <dd>3</dd>
       <dt>Peaches</dt>
   </dl>

   <dl id="idD"> 
       <dd>10</dd>
       <dt>Seadless Watermelons</dt>
   </dl>

   <dl id="idE"> 
       <dd>23</dd>
       <dt>Bananas</dt>
   </dl>
 </div>
```

The goal I am trying to achieve:
1. split each dl content into an array
2. find numbers and save them in "n"
3. find text and save them in "w"
4. wrap "n" with 'dd' tag
5. wrap "w" with 'dt' tag
6. the "n" & "w" should NOT have leading & trailing white spaces

Here is the code I came up, but it didn't work...

```
$("div.classA dl").each(function(){
      var a = $("div.classA dl").html();
      a = a.split(' ');
      var n = a.match(/d+/);
      var w = a.match(/D+/);
      $("div.classA dl").text('');
      $("div.classA dl").append('<dd>'n'</dd>');
      $("div.classA dl").append('<dt>'w'</dt>');

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's pretty much it, but you have a couple of small issues in your code:

1. To match a digit, use `\d` instead of just `d`. Same goes with `D`, where it should be `\D`;
2. [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) returns an array, thus you need to access the first position of it to obtain the matched value;
3. `$.each` already iterates over all `dl`s, no need to select them all again in each iteration of the loop. Just refer to the element that is being iterated, using `this`.

Here's the fixed code and a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qun5d/3)**:

```
$("div.classA dl").each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var text = $this.text();        
  var n = text.match(/\d+/)[0];
  var w = text.match(/\D+/)[0].replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g, '');

  $this.empty();

  $("<dd>").text(n).appendTo($this);
  $("<dt>").text(w).appendTo($this);
});​
```

Comment: Any idea if there is an alternative way to replace [0] after "match"? It seems my html editor won't do anything, but if I remove it the result changes but not correctly. It does work in jsFiddle though. Same thing for the \d & \D, it removed the \.

Comment: @user1672793: Your editor is removing the slash \? That's a very odd behaviour. Have you considered changing to another editor?

Comment: Yes, visually it appears to be, whether it's affecting the code running behind or not I don't know as [0] might have something to do with not working. This is the only editor I can paste my code as I am inserting jQuery code to change my vendor's html layout. The editor is theirs.

Comment: @user1672793: Try replacing /\d+/ with new RegExp("\\d+") (do the same with \D+). As for the `[0]`, it's just an array subscript, nothing special about that. Try isolating the result of match in a variable, and then sucscript it, i.e. `var arr = text.match(...); arr[0]`. Other than that, it's hard to tell you what you can do, this is just standard JavaScript, nothing really special about it that'd make an editor strip some characters out of it.

Comment: Thanks so much for helping me out. I will digest your instruction one at a time. A little overwhelming for now as I just started learning jQuery less than a month ago.